# Remove words form list sentences that have length < 3

Tags: python, file

I have an input file with sentences like this:

```
I like apples
My mother is called Anna.
```

I transfer these sentences to a list and then I want to remove words that have the length < 3.

I've tried this:

```
with open("fis.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    lst = [w.lower() for w in f.readlines() if len(w) >= 3]
    print(lst)
```

but it gives me `['i like apples', 'my mother is called anna.']`

and I want to obtain `['like apples', 'mother called anna.']`

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: `len(w) => 3` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("fis.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    print( [" ".join(j for j in w.split() if len(j) >= 3 ) for w in f.readlines() ] )
```

**Output:**

```
['like apples', 'mother called Anna.']
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`f.readlines()` gives you a list with two items which correspond to the two lines of the file.

You need to iterate over the lines (no need to read them into memory first, iterating over `f` will do), split each line, and then filter the words.

```
with open("fis.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    lst = [' '.join(w.lower() for w in line.split() if len(w) >= 3) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is taking the entire sentence and not individual words, try iterating through w and then check for length.